# Asynchronous map function that await's returns Promise instead of value

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs, arrow-functions

I have this code

```
async function addFiles(dir,tree) {
  return (await readDir(dir))
    .map(async (name) => {await readDir(dir); return name;})
}
```

but unfortunately, it just returns a bunch of promises, because there the async function in map is not waited upon. I'm wondering if there is any way to await the mapped function in the above code.

Comment: I believe `return Promise.all((await readDir(dir)).map(...));` should work. Not sure if it has to be `await Promise.all(...)`.

Comment: Good thinking! Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

try

```
async function addFiles(dir,tree) {
  const files = await readDir(dir)
  await Promise.all(files.map(async (name) => {await readDir(dir); return name;})
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using bluebird you can use this cleaner, shorter syntax with [Promise.map](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html)

```
async function addFiles(dir, tree) {
  const files = await readDir(dir);
  return Promise.map(files, async (name) => { await readDir(dir); return name; });
}
```